# Django model calls an API before save

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-admin

I have a Django model that needs to call an external API just before saving. The API call is irreversible so I want to call it only before the DB save happens.

My code looks something like this:

```py
class Model1(models.Model):
    some_string = models.CharField(max_length=100)

class Model2(models.Model):
    model1 = models.OneToOneField(Model1, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    num1 = models.IntegerField()
    num2 = models.IntegerField()
    api_output = models.models.JSONField()

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.api_output = API.call_method(self.num1, self.num2, self.model1.some_string)
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)
```

`Model2` objects can be created from Django Admin but also from the code using `Model2.objects.create()`.

I have 2 questions:

1. When creating an instance of `Model2` from Django Admin - if the API call fails (throws an exception) I'd like Django Admin to show a human-readable error instead of the 5xx error page. One way to do that is to have a `clean()` method but I don't want to call the API before the object is actually saved. Also, when using `Model2.objects.create()` the `clean()` method is not called. Is there a way to call the API inside `save()` and still have Django Admin print a nice error if the call fails?
2. I noticed that during `save()`, if the `OneToOneField` constraint is violated (for example trying to create 2 instances of `Model2` with the same instance of `Model1`), the validation happens after the API call which means the API is being called although the object is not valid. Is there a way to perform all validations before my code runs (which call the API)?

Answer (score 0):

You should use Django Signals for that kind of business logic, if you want to do something before saving a model check the `pre_save` [signal](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/signals/#pre-save).

If you want to use Django Admin, you have to work in your `admin.py` inside your app and override the `save_model` method of [ModelAdmin](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.save_model).

Comment: I'm not sure how `pre_save`, `post_save` and `save_model` can solve the 2 issues raised in the question. Can you please elaborate?
`save_model` expects the object to be saved so it doesn't fit the use-case of API failure.
`pre_save` and `post_save` don't check `OneToOneField` uniqueness or any other validation the model has.